# jquery carousel jumping bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built a horizontal accordion with jquery. I'm having a problem with it. When it animates from one panel to another there's a jump at the right hand edge of the carousel. I've tried everything to get rid of this...adding widths...changing the js..removing whitespace from html etc..any suggestions?

http://boudaki.com/testing/carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.iamntz.com/40/jquery-ui-accordion-jump-bug/

[http://dev.iamntz.com/166/jquery-accordion-tutorial/](http://dev.iamntz.com/40/jquery-ui-accordion-jump-bug/)

Two relatively reasoned through musings on that issue.

I have run into this previously - I think it is a particularly nasty little issue that the community on the pluging has been trying to find a workaround for.  The markup at the links above is probably a bit different but the application should be no different when adjusted to your case.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I'd actually tried that using a span around the div and then applying all the styles to the div. I uploaded a verison to the link above....it doesn't help :(